# How can I randomly select from prewritten strings in C#?

Tags: c#, string, random

I have 100 separate strings, and I want the program to display one of them randomly when I push a button.

Comment: how do you store the strings? and what button that would be?

Comment: so... "how do I generate a random number in a specific range in C#", and "how do I select an element from an array/list in C#" - should be fine...

Comment: generate a random number between 0 and 99 and pass that as an index to your collection.

Comment: When you searched on Google for "C# generate random number", what did you find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an array of your string value and pick the random value from array.

```
// String array like in below format.

string [] stringArray = new [] {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"}; // Make it accordingly

int ramdomNum = random.Next(0, stringArray.Length);

Console.Write(stringArray[ramdomNum]);
```

Hope this will help you.